# How to avoid loosing changes on the root filesystem when kernel upgrading?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, zfs, omnios

On Solaris and variants, it makes a zfs clone of the current `/` filesystem and installs the new kernel there. When rebooting you get the new `/`.

In my case I have a `/scripts` directory, so if I ever should go back to a previous kernel, then my `/scripts` would also get rolled back, which to me should be independent of with kernel I am on.

**Question**

How can I avoid **loosing** the changes made to the filesystem from the time the kernel upgrade is finished till the host is rebooted?

Is there a procedure I am not aware of, as even if you are very fast to reboot after the kernel upgrade, log entries could easily have been made, which you would never see.

Comment: Put /scripts on its own filesystem that is not affected.

Comment: Make a new ZFS dataset and put your scripts there. Or better yet, put your scripts in the _standard_ location, `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Moving things to `/usr/local/bin` won't help if it's still on the root filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described are Boot Environments (BE), which will be created automatically on system upgrades or manually with the `beadm` command.

You can have multiple independent BEs, although only a single one can be active at the same time. You also can update/modify each BE separately. Normally you would do that to test specific software versions or a full system upgrade, but it is not restricted to that.

From [Advantages to Maintaining Multiple Boot Environments](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21801/snap3.html#scrolltoc):

> Although only one boot environment can be active at a time, you can mount an inactive boot environment by using the `beadm mount` command. Then, you could use the `pkg` command with the alternate root (`-R`) option to install or update specific packages on that environment.

I just tried it, `beadm mount BeName` will mount BeName in a temp directory under `/tmp`, which is writeable. You could write a simple script to sync/copy your new or changed files to the old BE or vice versa.

The documentation also states that snapshots on BEs are possible (with `beadm create BeName@snapshotNamedescription`), which may be helpful if you want to track differences that occurred between two points in time (with `zfs diff`).